# Cannot get requested data from route

Tags: laravel

**Laravel 8, PHP 7.4.3 
Trying to get request ID from the route. In this case I want to get 52 from the route**
Being a basic problem, still creating issue for me.
 **My Route**   **http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/expense/52/edit**
 **My Code**
**ExpenseController.php**

```
// namespace App\Http\Controllers;
public function edit(Request $request, Expense $expense)
{
//I tried running each dd individually.
    dd( $request->get('id') ); //returns null
    dd( $request->id ); //returns null
    dd( $request['id'] ); // returns null
}
```

For reference to this controller, [check this](https://github.com/Chirag5528/expense_tracker/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ExpenseController.php)

Please note that the route is generated by **Route::resource** function in web.php file.
 I want to know how to get the ID from the route.
 I also tried to use **Custom Form Request** but again that fails as the id is null,
**IDRequest.php**

```
//namespace App\Http\Requests;
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

This approach also fails me. Please tell me what is it that I am missing. Link for [IDRequest](https://github.com/Chirag5528/expense_tracker/blob/master/app/Http/Requests/IDRequest.php)

Every help and hint is appreciated.

Comment: To get the route `{id}` paramenter, you should use the route method. In the Controller: `$request->route('id');`, in the FormRequest: `$this->route('id');`. But since "the route is generated by Route::resource function", you have to know the name of that parameter first, which is probably not id.

Answer (score 1):

```
// namespace App\Http\Controllers;
public function edit(Request $request, Expense $expense)
{

}
```

$request->get('id') looks for the id param in your form data or params.

Expense $expense will load the resource with primary key id 52 as per route value. You can fetch the id from $expense variable.

Comment: Yeah, $expense contains the complete Model Object ( actual data in protected 
"attributes" index).
But I still cannot get the id sent from the route. 
Please consider IDRequest.php. When I use custom form validation, I get an error ( The id field is required. )